# Configure VSCode debugger for C program

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gdb, vscode-debugger

I am trying to use VScode for debugging a C program. I have C/C++ Extension installed (C/C++ Intellisense v1.16.3 from Microsoft)

The issues that I am facing are:

1. "Variables" not getting displayed
2. Cannot use breakpoint (when I click "Debug C/C++", it kind of hang and exit)

The sequence I follow is:

1. "Terminal" > "Run Build Tasks"
   [Build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFFdZ.png)
2. Set breakpoints in source .c file
   [Breakpoints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akFxk.png)
3. Run "Debug C/C++ File"
   [Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6gge.png)

My simple C program is: input_validation.c

```
// input_validation.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num = 0;
    printf("Enter a number between 1-10: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    if (num > 0 && num <= 10)
        printf("Input accepted!\n");
    else
        printf("Error: number must be between 1-10.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Here are my .json files under .vscode/ directory:

1. launch.json

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "C/C++: gcc.exe build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

2. tasks.json

```json
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

3. c_cpp_properties.json

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "c99",
            "intelliSenseMode": "${default}"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Please note that I am using gcc and gdb from cygwin.

```
PS C:\Users\leeyo\Desktop\Udemy\C> gdb --version
GNU gdb (GDB) (Cygwin 12.1-1) 12.1
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
PS C:\Users\leeyo\Desktop\Udemy\C> gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 11.4.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO 
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

PS C:\Users\leeyo\Desktop\Udemy\C> which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
PS C:\Users\leeyo\Desktop\Udemy\C> which gdb
/usr/bin/gdb
```

Debug console output:
[image: debug console output]

Expectation:

- Able to set breakpoint
- Able to step through code
- Able to see variables in "Run and Debug" view

Actual behaviour:

- None of them works as expected